# Capturing video from webcam on a browser to save video on my serverside

Tags: php, jquery, flash

at first let me tell you my technical knowledge, its jquery, javascript and php.
I am trying to build an application where i am providing facility to record his own video throgh webcam( i know i may need flash for it). I am ok with the location where video will get saved, that means on clients machine or my server. I tried jquery's plugin for webcam, but it only offers to capture image not video.

please help me with it

Comment: how many images can you capture per second ?

Answer (score 1):

Afaik there is no non-flash/silverlight option to catpure webcam video through the browser at the moment. HTML5 has a draft spec for doing video capture, but no browser (except Opera) has implemented it yet I think.

Have a look at http://www.red5-recorder.com/ for an semi-out-of-the-box solution based on the Red5 open-source streaming server.

If you want to roll your own, you would need to look into streaming servers in order to accept data from the clients webcam. Look at e.g. Red5 (http://www.red5.org/). From flash, you would then have to connect to the server in order to stream the video across and save the data on the server. Don't know about a silverlight equivalent, but I'm sure a google search could help there.

Answer (score 1):

Red 5 will save and record just fine (as it's demos show) but if you want to tweak either the flash control or the filename/location the video is saved on the server you'll need Flash/ActionScript and Java skills.

-- Lee

Answer (score 0):

Wowza media is good option....you can recorder webcam video and save to server(aws).

http://www.wowza.com/